# How to programmatically select text in UITextField without the "range selectors" on the side

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have `UITextField`'s in my app which are in a `UITableView` and I want their text selected when I tap them, cause normally users will want to erase what's already there before entering new text. I have successfully done that, but the thing is when the text is selected, those ugly little blue "lollipops" used to select the range of selected text appear on the sides of the text. How do I get them to not appear? 
thanks!

my code(qty and numberOfPeople are the `UITextField`'s):

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<n; i++){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [self.itemTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if ([textField isEqual:cell.qty] || [textField isEqual:cell.numberOfPeople]){
            [textField selectAll:self];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try this self.selectedTextRange = nil;

Comment: if I do that then nothing is selected plus I have to tap the UITextField to be able to edit it :(

Comment: You can use an NSAttributedString with NSBackgroundColorAttributeName set to [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.894 blue1.0 alpha:1.0] to make it appear as if your text is highlighted. You would then need to add code to clear your text appropriately based on the user's action.